# How can I make the Field Separator be both a full stop and a space? (Bash Script)

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, aix

I'm trying to check that a list of servers all have valid PTR records.My issue is that to compare the list of servers afg Currently I have done the following:

```
hostlist=$(echo /locationOfhostfile | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } ; { print $4 }' | xargs -i host {})
```

This returns all the servers in the following format (name.location.com is IPAddress and also any aliases they have). I then do a dig -x on the servers as follows:

```
ptrrecords=$($(echo "$hostlist" | awk '{ print $3 }' | tr -d ',' | xargs -i dig +short -x {})
```

This returns just the names of the servers with valid PTR's. (name.location.com)
I now want to compare the two lists so I've created 2 more variables to shorten both lists to only have the server name.

```
finalhostlist=$(echo "$hostlist" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="." } ; { print $1 }')
finalptrrecords=$(echo "$ptrlist" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="." } ; { print $1 }')
```

My issue here when I compare the two variables is that 2 servers don't follow the normal naming convention (name.location.com) and as a result appear as *server is 10* as the first "." for that line is during the IP address. This issue takes place in the finalhostlist variable. 
How can I make the field separator for $finalhostlist a full stop or a space?

Apologies for the long winded way I have asked this question.

Comment: set the ifs. `IFS=". "`

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this yesterday to no avail. This worked now though so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[We] can use `FS="[. ]";` – amdixon